# How to get values from query to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

According to my research, in MSSQL there is not array varible, isn't it?
I want to get the result of a select query. Query returned more than 1 value. (You can see the query below, it returned more than 1 value and I cannot assign it.)

```
Declare @sp_name varchar(100)
set @sp_name = (select name from sys.procedures)
```

Are there any way to get the result to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [table variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx):

```
declare @results table (Name nvarchar(100))
insert into @results select name from sys.procedures
select * from @results
```

Comment: Thanks @adrift, I want to use the results each of them in ---SELECT * 
FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.MyProc','OBJECT') 
ORDER BY subentity_name, permission_name --- I have to replace dbo.MyProc with results, how can use a loop with table variable?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you want to use it, but you could either select and execute dynamic sql from that table, or use a cursor to loop through the rows.  See the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
set @sp_name = ''
select @sp_name = @sp_name +name+','  from sys.procedures
set @sp_name = left(@sp_name,len(@sp_name)-1)      -- Remove last comma
```

Now @sp_name will be a comma separated list.

You can also do

```
select @sp_name into #tmpList FROM sys.procedures
select * from #tmpList
```

You are right, no arrays, but hopefully either the comma list or temp table will do what you want..

Comment: First query part returns this : "sp_upgraddiagrams,sp_helpdiagrams,sp_helpdiagramdefinition,sp_creatediagram,sp_renamediagram,sp_alt" Have you got any idea why it is incomplete?

Comment: Increase the length of your size for sp_name, maybe to VARCHAR(max)

Comment: You are right! Thank you @Sparky... I want to vote up your answer but I need 3 more reputation :) when I have 3 more reputation, I will vote up :)